# CSCore SampleMixerSample clicking

Tags: cscore

I removed the audio file dialog from the SimpleMixerSample example and just have the two sine waves generating.  I get a click maybe every 2/3 of a second.

Is the buffer getting read faster than it's being created?  I'd like to get smooth continuous sound from whatever waveforms I generate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind.  It was the implementation of the `SineGenerator`.

Add a private variable to keep track of samples created:

```
private double _currentCount = 0;
```

then change the sine generation code to be off current count within frequency cycle:

```
    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        double dsr = (double) WaveFormat.SampleRate,
            fcycle = dsr/Frequency;

        for (int i = offset; i < offset + count; i++)
        {
            float sine = (float) (Amplitude *  Math.Sin(Math.PI*2.0*_currentCount/fcycle));
            buffer[i] = sine;
            _currentCount = (_currentCount + 1.0) % fcycle;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Smooth.  Oh yeah.

The `Phase` variable isn't in there but could be added back in really easy...